# Centered table-like layout with columns of equal widths using CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

On a web page, I have a row of submit buttons.

- This row of buttons should be centered on the page
- Each button should be as wide as the widest button (i.e no fixed/hard-coded button widths).

This is easily done with a `<table>`, but as people keep telling me those are bad for you, I wondered if this can be done with CSS instead. So, I have tried the `display: table` and `table-cell` CSS classes, but either the buttons don't get equal widths, or the longest button's caption gets clipped:

```
.button-row {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.button-row button {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
}

<div class="button-row" >
    <button>Short caption</button>
    <button>A much longer caption</button>
</div>
```

[image: Clipped button caption]

*Actually, it does look correct in IE, but not in **Chrome and Firefox**.* Here is a fiddle with both my table- and CSS-attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/kfwhpre8/

If possible, I would like to get rid of the `width: 50%` settings, because the number of buttons may vary, but that's easy enough to calculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your fiddle, keep in mind that in the table version the `buttons` are contained in `td`s. This is the essence of the problem. It appears using `table-cell` on buttons directly is problematic. If you don't mind chaniging your HTML you can try:

```
<div class="button-row">
    <div>
        <button>Short caption</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>A much longer caption</button>
    </div>
</div>


.button-row {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.button-row>div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
}

.button-row button {
    width:100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfwhpre8/4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works! Any idea if it's possible to do this without specifying the percentage for each button?

Answer (score 0):

prob not the answer you are looking for as you said you want to get rid of the `width:50%`

If you set the `width:100%` in the `button-row button{}`all the buttons will be as wide as the widest button

```
.button-row button {
   display: table-cell;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a good answer, but your link goes to my original JSFiddle, so I can't see your solution..

Comment: Sorry my bad will just add the code to change in my answer.

Comment: If I do that, the second button is placed below the first one, not side-by-side. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kfwhpre8/2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if this would suffice, as you'd have to check each time a new button was added, as to the best size for them. But you could simply add a width to each button and a margin to replicate the table layout.

At least in the HTML's current form.

```
.button-row button {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kfwhpre8/3/

Comment: Sorry, that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid :)